# How can I make my discord.js start at boot using node pi-4?

Tags: node.js, linux, discord.js, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I am new to linux in general so I may not be aware of certain things. So, I have tried multitudes of solutions but I haven't succeeded in running the discord.js bot. I have used `rc.local` with other scripts like writing date on a file on startup `date > <file-path>` and it works properly, but somehow running bot on startup fails and can't quite read any errors either.

`rc.local` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e

_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/bin/sh /home/pi/superscript.sh

exit 0
```

`superscript.sh` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

date > /home/pi/boot.log

( cd /home/pi/Desktop/discord-bot; /usr/bin/node /home/pi/Desktop/discord-bot/index.js ) &
```

The bot works completely fine when I manually execute it `node ~/Desktop/discord-bot/index.js &` and it even works if I manually execute `superscript.sh`, so I can't really find the problem. Can anyone help me out please I would really appreciate it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way is to use crontab to execute commands on startup

```
# Edit cron
crontab -e

# type following to start a script-file.sh on startup
@reboot script-file.sh
```

reference: https://www.simplified.guide/linux/automatically-run-program-on-startup